# Helm (go template) to generate an ssh key and display the public part

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I can generate an ssh key with Sprig quite easily. But ideally I just need to put it in k8s secrets and display the public part to the user to import on the remote end.

https://play.golang.org/p/9oFBr9LD190
(for a full go example, but I don't get Go, just sprig in Helm.)

The Helm template alone just needs the template bit :
`{{ genPrivateKey "rsa" }}` to show the text of a key to go into secrets. But other than giving the user the command to query the key from the secret and run it through ssh-keygen :

`kubectl get secret ... -o jsonpath=".data.ssh-key" | base64 -d | ssh-keygen -y -f/dev/stdin`

is there a way to persuade Sprig to get the public part of the key? (Commands unchecked, but you get the idea.)

Comment: It looks like [Sprig's cryptographic functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/crypto.html) don't include a way to extract the public key (hence the `... | ssh-keygen` invocation in the `NOTES.txt` output).  There are some practical problems generating random values like this in Helm in any case: there's no way to retrieve the old random key and so on an upgrade it will regenerate it.  You might be better off injecting the key directly as a Helm value or requiring the operator to create the Secret, rather than generating it yourself.

Comment: "(lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace  .Release.Name ).data.ssh-privatekey " would get the key quite easily and can be wrapped in an "if" statement to avoid recreating a key (which I don't want) and also setting the "helm.sh/resource-policy: keep" avoids it being deleted with the deployment. Putting the key in values etc.. would require the user to create it first. I was hoping to have a single "helm upgrade --install ...." command without any other magic that causes confusion.